# Nested floating divs cause outer div to not grow

Tags: css, css-float

*If anyone can suggest a better place than stackoverflow for css questions please let me know.*

I have an outer div with background and border and then I need to have two columns within the colored box. Some reason when I place the floating divs inside the outer div, the outer div does not grow.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="tip_box">
    <h3>Send</h3>
    <hr />
    <form id="email_form">

        <div class="three-columns">
            <div class="contact_form_input">
                <h6>Your Name</h6>
                <input type="text" name="name_text_box" class="form_input" id="name_text_box" />
            </div>
            <div class="contact_form_input">
              <h6>Your Email</h6>
              <input type="text" name="email_text_box" class="form_input" id="email_text_box" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="three-columns">
            <div class="contact_form_input">
                <h6>Recipient Name</h6>
                <input type="text" name="name_text_box" class="form_input" id="Text1" />
            </div>
            <div class="contact_form_input">
              <h6>Recipient Email</h6>
              <input type="text" name="email_text_box" class="form_input" id="Text2" />
            </div>
        </div>

    </form>
</div>

<p>This is where your message will go. Anything you want, as long as you want. Make it personal; make the recipient know you care.</p>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.three-columns {
    width: 290px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 45px;
}
.tip_box {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 20px 0px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    padding-left: 55px;
    background: #eee;
    font-style:italic;
    background: #eff7d9 url(../images/icons/tip.png) no-repeat scroll 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid #b7db58;
    color: #5d791b;
}
```

Screenshot:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2127038/cssissue.png

Comment: I love how you put an image to clearly demonstrate the problem you were having. Really made it quick and easy to see the problem you're describing is exactly the same one I was looking to solve. +1

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Non-float blocks containing float blocks will not automatically expand, since float blocks are taken outside the normal flow (or at least specially outside the flow). One way to correct that is to specify the `overflow` property to `hidden` or `auto`.

```
.tip-box { overflow: auto; }
```

See [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for more.

Comment: overflow auto will cause scrollbars. hidden is preferred.

Comment: Certainly not always, but a good thing to mention. It will happen only if you run up against the edges of the box with something (and you can work around that). You should also mention that `overflow:hidden` has the potential to chop off content like images that `overflow` the box.

Comment: (As you may guess, I prefer `auto`. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Add following HTML after `<div class="tip_box"></div>`:

```
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.clear{
clear:both;
}
```

It will surely work.

Answer (score 2):

```
.tip_box { overflow:hidden; zoom:1; }
```

this establishes new block formatting context in ie7+ and other browsers, triggers haslayout in ie6 to contain floats

Comment: +1 for the haslayout explanation, though the poster should still look at [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html) for a complete explanation :)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need what is commonly known as a clearfix. In this case a `overflow: hidden` on the containing element will do - see: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/zuNwH/2

```
.tip_box {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

As an aside, you might also want to use `label` elements instead of `h6` to markup labels for your form elements, and use a list instead of individual `div`s for containing each `label - input` pair, and reduce the amount of `class` attribute you use by relying on more complex selectors for your CSS file.

```
<li>
    <label for="recipient_email">Recipient Email</label>
    <input type="text" name="email_text_box" id="recipient_email" />
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case I wouldn't float the divs left, I would make them display: inline or inline-block.

Your 3 columns will turn into 2 columns, then 1 column if the browser window shrinks.

Comment: -1 The poster obviously wanted the blocks to be aligned next to each other. Float is the accepted way to do this. `inline-block` would be useful, but it isn't supported by IE6 or IE7 unless you do some painful roundabout hacks, which happen in this case to be completely unnecessary. And `inline` would not have an effect anywhere near what seems to be intended; might as well not have the divs at all.